# Zonal statistics batch process using QGIS

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, batch

I am working with QGIS 3.34.3-Prizren and I carried out a rasteranalysis using zonal statistics batch process. I have some problems choosing the right autofill settings for the column spatial statistics-autofill.

- Input: vector layer "geo" (5 biogeregions within a country)
- Rasterlayer: 15 layers "spA", "spB", "spC"....

If I use the autofill settings `fill with parameter values`, I get "geo1", "geo2", "geo3", but I would like "geoA", "geoB", "geoC" to didfferentiate between species A, B, C...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  Autofill settings: fill with paramater values. Then choose Raster layer.